# Mouse receiver stopped working after pairing mouse to an unifying receiver

Tags: mouse, connection, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

I bought this mouse, logitech m510, which came with a nano receiver (no-unifying).
Yes I know, the mouse is supposed to come with a unifying receiver but I bought it knowing that it won't come on it's original package and it will come with a no-unifying receiver.

When I received it, everything worked ok but, after connecting the mouse to another computer using an unifying receiver (that also worked ok, btw), then, when I tried to connect back the mouse to my computer using the no-unifying receiver, I couldn't connect it.

I tried everything from removing the batteries and reinstalling the drivers to restarting the computer and trying in different computers, but I couldn't connect them.

What I think it happened, is that in fact if you check the documentation of the logitech m510 it says that it works with unifying receivers only, and even more, there is the following article explaining it: http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18001/~/using-my-m510-with-a-different-usb-receiver

So my theory is that the problem was connecting it to a unifying receiver, and now, isn't recognize by another receiver.

The receiver (the no-unifying one) itself is recognized by windows, and if I connect the mouse using a unifying receiver, it works.

I would like to know if there is any know solution for this or if I can try something else to see if I can solve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the end, after asking the seller for a solution to my problem, he sent me the following link:
http://support.logitech.com/software/logitech-connection-utility-software

It's the software **Logitech Connection Utility**, copy pasted from the link I put above: "It can be used to reconnect supported keyboards or mice with a replacement receiver or when the connection is lost."

It solved instantly the problem I described in my question.

Comment: Great share. Just to add here, `Logitech Connection Utility` can be installed on any computer that has not been used previously with the mouse in problem with connection. So, use the tool on any PC and re-connect the mouse. Once you are done, put the non-unifying receiver back to the original PC and the mouse should now get connected. In a nutshell, I believe the `Logitech Connection Utility` is a tool to configure the mouse firmware to recognize the non-unifying receiver.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Receiver did not work at old comp after using it on another With Logitech software installed and unifying. My mouse was an MX (unifying receiver) . I had to install the Logitech (unifying) software. The mouse still wasnt recognized. I had to ununifye it on the comp i had used it on once when my MX was on, then my old comp could recognize it. Problem solved...